# DateTime Format Handling

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datetime, windows-phone-8

I have a program that has synchronization. That means I need to save the last synchronization date and check if it needs to be synchronized.

So, I have this:

```
IS.SaveContactsRetrieveDate(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
```

Saving a date to Isolated Storage.

Then, when I call IF:

```
DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now;

string contactsRetriveDate = IS.ReadContactsRetriveDate();
if (contactsRetriveDate == "" || DateTime.Compare(toDate, DateTime.Parse(contactsRetriveDate)) == 1)
{
    MessageBox.SHow("");
}
```

The problem is that when user changes the region code fails here:

```
DateTime.Compare(toDate, DateTime.Parse(contactsRetriveDate))
```

With incorrect input error.

I understand that Latvian format is `dd.MM.yyyy` and USA `MM/dd/yyyy` - but I can't find a solution...

I need all datetime parsed in one format, so I could add days, weeks and compare date.

Comment: Well you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` with the format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ParseExact

```
DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

you already know format so you can go for this, but make sure the string is in same format and never changes.

Answer (score 2):

You should serialize *and* deserialize your date in a culture-independent manner (where `"d"` is the "Short date pattern" of the [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)):

```
var s = DateTime.Now.ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var d = DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

u can try this one:

```
 DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now;

                string contactsRetriveDate = IS.ReadContactsRetriveDate();
                DateTime contactsRetriveDat = Convert.ToDateTime(contactsRetriveDate);
                if (contactsRetriveDate == "" || toDate.CompareTo(contactsRetriveDat)==0)
                {
                    MessageBox.SHow("");
                }
```